# Django, Unable to view certain database information

Tags: django, database, sqlite, data-retrieval

I've been working on a project and I've been stuck for over a week and haven't been able to find the solution to this problem.

I'm creating a school management app. I've successfully allowed the teachers to create a schedule, allowed the students to view it and select it as part of their class. The problem I'm running into is that the teacher is not able to see the students information after they've chosen a class.

For models I have:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    englishName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studentName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studentId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    gradeLevel = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    since = models.DateField()
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=13, default=00000000)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default='address@email.com')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.studentName

def index(request):
    data=Student
    context = {'form': data}
    return render(request, 'student-information.html', context)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    time = models.TimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    duration = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __datetime__(self):
        return self.date + '' + self.student

def index(request):
    data = Schedule
    context = {'form': data}
    return render(request, 'set-schedule.html', context)
```

For my views file I have:

```
@login_required
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['teacher'])
def dailySchedule(request):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(date=today)
    students = []
    for schedule in schedules:
        students.append(schedule.student)
    context = {'today': datetime.now().date(), 'schedules': schedules, 'students': students}
    return render(request, 'eslbeeph/daily-schedule.html', context)
```

and for the html file I have:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="daily-schedule-title">
        <h3 class="daily-schedule-header">Schedule</h3>
    </div>
<!--Information to be obtained by from the database.-->
    <div class="daily-schedule-table">
        <table class="daily-schedule">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th colspan="6">{{ today|date:"F d, Y" }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Class Status</th>
                <th>Student Profile</th>
            </tr>
            {% for schedule in schedules %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ schedule.time|date:"H:i" }}</td>
                {% for student in students %}
                    <td>{{ schedule.student.user.username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ schedule.duration }}</td>
                    <td>{{ schedule.student.studentId }}</td>
                    <td>{{ schedule.student.englishName }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                <td>{ status }</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Now, There's a lot more code to the project but these are the areas I think are causing the problem. I've tried a number of different things to get this to work, but nothing's worked.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong or what I need to do let me know. I appreciate any help anyone can give me.

What I've been trying to do is get the a table to show up with the schedule time, the user name of the student who selected the schedule, the number of minutes the teacher stated the class would be, the students id number, and the students english name. The class status and the button for the students profile I plan to handle later.

Right now the time and the class length show up fine. But no matter what I do I cannot get the students user name, english name, and ID to populate at all.

Any tips, examples, or guesses as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

***EDIT***
After doing a bit more work I found that the Student model is not connecting to the Schedule model. So, the problem is different from what I originally suspected. It's not that the student information isn't being shown. It's that the schedule a student selects isn't recognizing the student has selected it.

Comment: Should `student` in your Schedule model not be of type `ManyToManyField`? Because right now, you have only one student per Schedule. If you use `ManyToManyField` you will have any student related to a Schedule automatically with `schedule.students.all()`.

Comment: @Marco, the student should be able to select multiple schedules but each schedule should only have 1 student. For example, the schedule for February 27 at 12:00pm would have only the student John. But John could have 5 different schedules selected. 

With that in mind, using ManyToManyField wouldn't work. I need one student to many schedules.

Comment: Ok, got it. You can close the question and ask a new question why the student is not linked to the schedule when creating an object.